# How to load an external pickle file contents as a data frame in azure ml studio in the 'execute python script' section?

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

This is script which I am using:

```
 import warnings
 warnings.filterwarnings('ignore') 
 import pandas as pd
 import sys
 import pickle
 def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):
 sys.path.append('.\\Script Bundle')
 dataframe1 = pickle.load(open(r'/Script Bundle/descript.pkl', 'rb'))
 return dataframe1,
```

but when I execute it , getting below error

```
 FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Script 
 Bundle/descript.pkl'
 Process returned with non-zero exit code 1
```

Comment: Somewhat related but important point - pickling data is not a very good practice from a security standpoint. You're better off reading/writing json. [Here's why](https://www.benfrederickson.com/dont-pickle-your-data/)

Answer (score 1):

The model is available under `'./Script Bundle'`, you don't need the whole `sys.path.append` thing. So you can use something like the code below:

```python
import pandas as pd
import pickle

def azureml_main(dataframe1 = None, dataframe2 = None):

    model = pickle.load( open( "./Script Bundle/iris.pkl", "rb" ) )
    cleanFrame = dataframe1[['sepal-length','sepal-width','petal-length','petal-width']]

    prediction = model.predict(cleanFrame)

    dataframe1['Scored Labels'] = prediction

    return dataframe1
```

You can take a look at [this ML Studio experiment](https://gallery.azure.ai/Experiment/Custom-Python-model-integration-using-the-Iris-dataset) for an example.